# Populating sql table from multiple sources

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is my setup:

old tables

```
Location [ID, Country, Region]
IpAddress [ID, IP]
Session [ID, IpAddressId, LocationId]
```

new tables

```
Country[ID, Country]
Region[ID, Region]    
IpAddress[ID, IP]
Profile[ID, IpAddressId, CountryId, RegionId]
Session[ID, ProfileId]
```

I have already deconstructed the Location table.  Now I'm getting lost in the weeds on how to insert to the Profile table, and associate it with the session.  To note, the old Location table still exists and I don't plan on dropping it till the Profile table is completely updated.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the new `Session` table achieve here?  It seems the purpose of that table is being replaced by the new `Profile` table.

Comment: Its abbreviated, it has other columns and FKs, but I am just concerned with the ones listed.

Comment: Problem is, those other columns and FKs are what you will need to join on to create the new `Session` table...  I think my answer will provide the concept, but if you want help with the specific query, we would need to know that stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the `Profile` table you need to build a query that connects the relations of each table, but you can't use your `id` columns to link the new tables to the old, since those are no longer relational.  This should work for you:

```
--INSERT INTO Profile (IpAddressId, CountryId, RegionId)
SELECT S.IpAddressId, C.ID, R.ID
FROM   Session S --Old Session table
INNER JOIN Location L on S.LocationId = L.ID
INNER JOIN Country C on C.Country = L.Country
INNER JOIN Region R on R.Region = L.Region
```

Note: this is assuming that the `IpAddress` table will remain unchanged, and use the same `IpAddressId`.

That said, I think your issue is how to link this to the new `Session` table.  To answer that, we would need to know what the new `Session` table will do.. but in general, you would go about populating it in the same way as the above query.  Join it to the corresponding tables on the matching *data* in order to get the new `id` relations.